# LocationManager always returning 1.000000 as latitude and longitude

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, locationmanager

In my app I have implemented onLocationChanged to get the current location through GPS however each time it gets called a string value is updates with latitude and longitude value of 1.000000

**In onCreate I wrote**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

**onLocationChanged**

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        location = arg0.getLatitude() + " " + arg0.getLongitude();


    }
```

I implemented the LocationListener and have the the following permission to the app and I am testing this in a real device. I am sending the location value to webserver which when received shows 1.0000000.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: could you post log.d inside onlocationchanged()

Comment: what is the type of variable location??

Comment: location is a string and I tried using a double as well with no success.